# How to hide (or remove) a pre-configured layer from the layers-panel in WorldWind

Tags: java, layer, jogl, worldwind

I would like to hide one of the "standard" layers (such as Stars, atmosphere, nasa blue marble and so on) in the layer panel, and to visualize and to make enabled/disabled by ticks only layers added by me. Naturally, the hidden layers have to be always active. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you want to remove the layers, or do you want to remove the option that the end-user has to remove the layers (that is, remove the check-boxes in the sample window) so that the end-user cannot remove those layers?

Comment: I think you guys are missing the nuances of the question. The user is asking whether it is possible to remove one (or more) of the pre-configured layers from the layer-panel so that it cannot be ticked and unticked from there. Thus, the layer should still be added to the list of layers, but not be available for toggling in the layer-panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this method.

```
private void removeLayerWithName(String str) {
    wwd.getModel().getLayers().forEach(layer -> {
        if (layer.getName().equals(str)) {
            wwd.getModel().getLayers().remove(layer);
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

and in your code you call it as `removeLayerWithName("Stars");`.

Other layer-names that may be useful for you:

- Stars
- Atmosphere
- NASA Blue Marble Image
- Blue Marble May 2004
- i-cubed Landsat

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove layers programmatically use @sayyedbagher solution. Another solution is changing the initial settings of WorldWind by providing an xml file containing initial settings (including initial layers). Base on documents of `gov.nasa.worldwind.Configuration` class here https://worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/java/latest/javadoc/index.html?gov/nasa/worldwind/Configuration.html and comments in the file `worldwind.xml` here https://github.com/nasa/World-Wind-Java/blob/master/WorldWind/src/config/worldwind.xml you could determine yourself initial layers as permanent initial settings of WorldWind in your app.