# How to remove the compass from nasa worldwind

Tags: java, swing, worldwind

[image]

I am working on a project related with nasa worldwind.

Can anybody explain how can I remove the compass ,which is

located at the top right of screen.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. We have **no** idea what you are doing, and what exactly you are referring to ...

Answer (score 0):

simply remove the following code from your Javascript file:

`wwd.addLayer(new WorldWind.CompassLayer());`

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged the question with `swing` and `java` tags I assume you are referring to WorldWindJava and the solution in the other answer related to WebWorldWind will not work. To remove the compass layer from WorldWind you can do it either programmatically or via the `worldwind.layers.xml` file.

For a programmatic approach you can look at this question:

[How to Hide(or remove the) Standard layer (like star,atmosphere,earth at night) in World wind java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51056384/how-to-hideor-remove-the-standard-layer-like-star-atmosphere-earth-at-night)

and then call that method there as: `removeLayerWithName("Compass")`.

The XML configuration file approach is the easiest and you can see a full example of the `worldwind.layers.xml` file [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NASAWorldWind/WorldWindJava/develop/src/config/worldwind.layers.xml). So, basically you copy that file, remove the:

```
<Layer className="gov.nasa.worldwind.layers.CompassLayer"/>
```

entry there at the bottom. You then need to place this file in a folder that is located in your application's current-working-directory. I suggest you give it a unique name to differentiate it from the default `worldwind.layers.xml` file for example `worldwind.custom.layers.xml`. You then need to specify that WorldWind should use this custom file by modifying the `worldwind.xml` file. You can get a template of this file [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NASAWorldWind/WorldWindJava/develop/src/config/worldwind.xml). Copy this file to the same folder in your application's current-working-directory. Also give it a different name like `worldwind.custom.xml`. You then need to modify this entry:

```
<LayerList href="config/worldwind.layers.xml"/>
```

in `worldwind.custom.xml` to point to your file like so:

```
<LayerList href="some-folder/worldwind.custom.layers.xml"/>
```

Lastly, you need to specify that WorldWind should use your custom configuration file via the `gov.nasa.worldwind.app.config.document` system property. So, if you have a script to launch your app you add the following in your `run.sh` file:

```
java -cp "...classpath-stuff" -Dgov.nasa.worldwind.app.config.document="some-folder/worldwind.custom.xml" com.example.MainClass
```